# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, can't find the error

Tags: php

This code works fine local (xampp) after uploading I'm receiving Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, but can't seem find out what's the problem.

```
$user = $_GET["u"];
$order = $_GET["o"];

$fullorder = $user . $order . ".txt";

include("geoip.inc");
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function loghit()
{
$user = $_GET["u"];
$order = $_GET["o"];

$fullorder = $user . $order . ".txt";
$lf_name = $fullorder;


$monthly = 0;

$monthly_path = "oldfiles";

$type = 1;


$display = 1;


$separator = "<br \>";


$log_file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $lf_name;


    $uIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (file_exists($log_file)) {
        if (date('j') == 10) {
            if (!file_exists($monthly_path)) {
                mkdir($monthly_path);
            }

            $prev_name = $monthly_path . '/' . date("n-Y", strtotime("-1 month"));
            if (!file_exists($prev_name)) {
                copy($log_file, $prev_name);

                if ($type == 0) {
                    $toWrite = "1";
                    $info = $beforeAllText . "1";
                } else if ($type == 1) {
                    $toWrite = "1;" . $uIP . ",";
                    $info = $beforeUniqueText . "1";
                } else if ($type == 2) {
                    $toWrite = "1;1;" . $uIP . ",";
                    $info = $beforeAllText . "1" . $separator . $beforeUniqueText . "1";
                }
                goto write_logfile;
            }
        }
```

write_logfile file is further down in the code:

```
write_logfile:
    //Put $toWrite in log file
    file_put_contents($log_file, $toWrite);

}
```

Error occurs on this line:

```
                goto write_logfile;
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: where is write_logfile is defined in code..??? you need to add write_logfile label..

Comment: I didn't realize people were actually using `goto` since it was introduced

Comment: Sorry, edited the main post.

Comment: Just to check the obvious: goto is only available in PHP >= 5.3.0; What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Oh well yes, just had updated local webserver, didn't really thought about on remote webserver, that solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, your code doesn't seem like a prime candidate for a goto statement; consider using functions instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

The `goto` command is only available in PHP >= 5.3.0. If you attempt to use `goto` otherwise, you'll get an unexpected T_STRING error.

---

**BEFORE:**

You need to add a label in your code for `goto` to reach.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

add `write_logfile:` where you expect your code to jump to.

Comment: Isn't that already in his code?

Comment: And that is why one has to be sure that one has the correct PHP version on server and local...